# Why aren't my attribute selectors working?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to use multiple attribute selectors, but my code just doesn't seem to work at least in CodePen...

I googled a lot, but I just can't find a solution.

I've written them in SCSS:

```
*[class^="inset"] {
  &[class*="-t0"] {
    top: 0;
  }
  &[class*="-r0"] {
    right: 0;
  }
  &[class*="-b0"] {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  &[class*="-l0"] {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

here's a runnable demo with compiled CSS:

```css
*[class^="inset"][class*="-t0"] {
  top: 0;
}
*[class^="inset"][class*="-r0"] {
  right: 0;
}
*[class^="inset"][class*="-b0"] {
  bottom: 0;
}
*[class^="inset"][class*="-l0"] {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="inset-t0">Button</button>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML as well. Can't really figure out what you're trying to select without it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: why are you not try with mixin

Comment: Are they not working in Sass? Or not working in CSS?

Comment: Also, it's unclear *what* isn't working. Are you expecting directional position properties here to apply without having applied a `position` property? If so then you have other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting like this implies there are two css classes in the element, like

`<button class="inset -t0"></button>`

You can simply do the following:

```
.inset {
  &-t0 {
    top: 0;
  }
  &-r0 {
    right: 0;
  }
  &-b0 {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  &-l0 {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: We must go to the simplest

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but you adressed the problem I couldn't find. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
.inset {
  &-t0 {
    top: 0;
  }

  &-r0 {
    right: 0;
  }

  &-b0 {
     bottom: 0;
  }

  &-l0 {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation and/or description to your code. Code-only answers *may* solve the problem, but they just as likely may not, and it shouldn't be left as an exercise to readers to dissect your code (After all, hell is other people's code).